# jquery.get not doing an xhr request on Firefox

Tags: python, jquery, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I have just entered the world of jquery and am pretty new to javascript too. I have a small javascript snippet like below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $('a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get('/_add_navigation_',function(response){
        $('#themaincontents').html(response);
        })
   })
</script>
```

The html looks like this:-

```
<a href="?toaddnavigation">CLICK Me</a>
<div id="themaincontents"></div>
```

On the server side I do an xhr header check by something like

```
 if request.is_xhr: send response else:redirect somewhere
```

Now while this code works fine on Chrome and Opera, on Firefox it is behaving a little weird. The server does not send back the reponse, but rather does a redirect. That means it says that there is no xhr header. Why should this happen while on the other two browsers it is working fine?
(I am using Firefox 3.6.12)
Update - I just had a look at the request headers of Firefox and I find no `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` header, but it is present in Chrome.

Comment: I think you are trying to solve a non-problem.  It shouldn't be possible for a user to navigate (via links) to `/_add_navigation_`, and any user sophisticated enough and devious enough to try and manualy open that resource in a browser, would expect an error or non-human friendly response anyway.

Comment: I agree , but then that is not the agenda, the agenda is to do it this way. Why should the headers not be set, what is that i am doing wrong!

Comment: i think now you're asking to set headers sent by the browser in javascript: this CANNOT BE DONE (see http://www.csschat.com/showthread.php?t=8868)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all browsers send the same headers, and you cannot rely on them to be consistent across browsers. The easiest way is to not rely on the browser to send something, but manually send something yourself:

```
$.get('url', {
    xhr: 'yes' // add this extra parameter here
}, function(){

});
```

then check for that GET variable on the server instead of a header that may or may not be sent by a browser.

Comment: While this deinitely looks a cool technique, I would want to do it the headers way. Cant seem to understand what I might have done wrong.

Comment: @Alice, the point is that you aren't doing anything wrong, and that you cant reliably do it with headers

Comment: @alice @mikerobi is correct. you MUST do it this way (or similar), as you CANNOT do it only with headers, as you have found out: some browsers don't have the header.